# Accessing UIWindow from AppDelegate.swift in Objective-C file

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on swift project where I need to use my old `Objective-C` code.

I did managed to create `-Bridge-Header.h` file and it works for me.

now in my `Objective-C` code I need to refer `UIWindow` from `AppDelegate.swift`,

Can any one has done this before?

Please guide me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First to access the Swift classes in ObjC ,you could import the compiler generated header file to expose those files to ObjC. It would be like `ProductModuleName-Swift.h`.(This file doesn't really exists to see,but Xcode will automatically create it for you)

```
#import "YourProductName-Swift.h"
```

Then you can access the `window` property in the app delegate from the ObjC file like

```
AppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIWindow *window = delegate.window;
```

Comment: how can i import the compiler generated header file?

Comment: Like importing any other file #import "YourProductName-Swift.h". `YourProductName` will be same as app target name

Comment: i did import "#import "MyProjectName-Swift.h" but it shows me an error "file not found".

Comment: Is your app target name is `MyProjectName`?

Comment: yes, my project and targer both have the same name as `MyProjectName`

Comment: Check it properly, if its right it wont give any error. Read more about https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_74

Comment: I have implement the following type in my project "To import Objective-C code into Swift from the same framework", I have create `Swift` project and importing the `Objective-C` code into the project, and it works fine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57914/discussion-between-icoder86-and-anil).

Comment: Thanks It helps me, Due to some error my project was miss configured.. So i created a new project and tried it.. and it worked